# Ghostscript strips Alt Text

Tags: accessibility, ghostscript, pdf-conversion

I work with an app called ICMS (Integrated Case Management System), and documents are submitted to this app in .docx format. Many times they need to include images and we require "Alt Text" to be added to each image. Once the document is added to ICMS I can see the Alt Text is still there, but when the document is signed by an admin user the document goes through a conversion from .docx to pdf. From my understanding ICMS is using Ghostscript for that conversion and when that conversion happens, it strips/deletes the Alt Text. Has anyone had this issue before? Are there any kind of DocStructureTags within Ghostscript that are possibly set to False? If so, where can we find them? Any insight would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Ghostscript does not 'strip text'. Most likely your conversion from .docx involves printing to a PDF printer or something, and that is converting the input to a bitmap. If presented with a bitmap, then that's what Ghostscript's pdfwrite device puts in the output file, it has no choice.  You would need to take up the problem with the Department for International Trade, who appear to run ICMS. If they are using Ghostscript, then it's as a free user, so they get no support from Artifex.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by 'Alt text'. While this may make sense to a docx user, it doesn't mean anything in PDF. I don't know what you're expecting to see. But in any event, ICMS can't be using Ghostscript to convert .docx to PDF, because Ghostscript doesn't take .docx as an input, so it must be getting converted to 'something else' first. Whether any non-printing stuff survives that conversion depends on the process, but it's not likely.

Comment: @KenS, "alt text" **does** have meaning for PDF.  It's the alternative text for images.  If you view the tags structure for a PDF, a `<figure>` element will have an "alternate text" property that can either be set manually, or if the PDF is generated from a Word doc (as you mentioned), then it comes from Word's "Description" property under "Alt Text" under "Layout & Properties".

Comment: @dakota, make sure the word document has the alt text set correctly. The **Description** property must be set. If you set the **Title** property, that is **not** the alt text. If it's set correctly, try generating a PDF from a sample Word doc yourself (outside of ICMS). Don't use print. Use "save as" and choose PDF as the saved file type.  You might have to select the options button then check "Document structure tags for accessibility". Then inspect the tagged PDF in acrobat to look at the alt text properties for the image.

Comment: @slugolicious I did that and when I look at the Accessibility Report the only issue it found was under "Page Content".. "Tab order - Failed". Once that's corrected and I upload the document into ICMS as a PDF there's still no Alt Text attached to the image.

Comment: @KenS if Ghostscript doesn't take .docx, then what all does it accept? Or is the list too long? lol

Comment: @Dakota; PostScript and PDF only. GhostPDL (all the Ghost* products in one) can also do PCL and XPS and a few image formats such as JPEG).

Comment: @sluolicious; If you mean the /Alt member of a structure element, sure, but its not called "Alt text". It also applies to elements which are not images. As I noted in my second comment, anything which isn't a marking operation would have to be passed on via something like a pdfmark. I very much doubt whatever conversion is taking place from .docx is preserving that. But it's not Ghostscript dumping it, it's likely happening before getting that far.